# Solution to Google Code Jam 2008 round 1C problem B

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

This is my solution to [Google Code Jam 2008 round 1C problem B](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32015/dashboard#s=p1) (Ugly Numbers). I think it's very elegant. However, I wonder if it's *too* concise. What could I improve here?

The problem:

> Once upon a time in a strange situation, people called a number ugly
>   if it was divisible by any of the one-digit primes (2, 3, 5 or 7).
>   Thus, 14 is ugly, but 13 is fine. 39 is ugly, but 121 is not. Note
>   that 0 is ugly. Also note that negative numbers can also be ugly; -14
>   and -39 are examples of such numbers.
>
> One day on your free time, you are gazing at a string of digits,
>   something like:
>
> 123456
>
> You are amused by how many possibilities there are if you are allowed
>   to insert plus or minus signs between the digits. For example you can
>   make
>
> 1 + 234 - 5 + 6 = 236
>
> which is ugly. Or
>
> 123 + 4 - 56 = 71
>
> which is not ugly.
>
> It is easy to count the number of different ways you can play with the
>   digits: Between each two adjacent digits you may choose put a plus
>   sign, a minus sign, or nothing. Therefore, if you start with D digits
>   there are 3^D-1 expressions you can make.
>
> Note that it is fine to have leading zeros for a number. If the string
>   is "01023", then "01023", "0+1-02+3" and "01-023" are legal
>   expressions.
>
> Your task is simple: Among the 3^D-1 expressions, count how many of
>   them evaluate to an ugly number.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of the input file contains the number of cases, N. Each
>   test case will be a single line containing a non-empty string of
>   decimal digits.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, you should output a line
>
> Case #X: Y
>
> where X is the case number, starting from 1, and Y is the number of
>   expressions that evaluate to an ugly number.

Code:

```
from functools import lru_cache

M = 2*3*5*7
uglies = list(filter(lambda n: (int(n)%2 == 0 or
                                int(n)%3 == 0 or
                                int(n)%5 == 0 or
                                int(n)%7 == 0),
                     range(M)))

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(line, k=None):
    if k == None:
        return sum([f(line, k) for k in uglies])

    return sum([
        (1 if (int(line) % M) == k else 0),

        sum([f(line[:p],
               (k-int(line[p:])) % M)
             for p in range(1, len(line))]),

        sum([f(line[:p],
               (k+int(line[p:])) % M)
             for p in range(1, len(line))]),
        ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    data = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()[1:]
    case = 1
    for line in data:
        print('{:.0%}'.format(case/len(data)), file=sys.stderr)
        print('Case #{}: {}'.format(case,
                                    f(line)))
        case += 1
```

Comment: Please add a language tag. Please add the problem description to your question. Please use a title which describes the code in question.

Comment: @Heslacher done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `k is None` case does not share any code with the recursive case, it would definitely be better as a separate function. Also, the prefixes and suffixes are now computed twice. I would use a separate function to generate them, or in fact a generator.

Here's how I would rearrange the code of `f`. Note the docstrings and more descriptive naming.

```
def all_splits(line):
    '''Split line into every possible pair of non-empty
    prefix and suffix'''
    for i in range(1, len(line)):
        yield line[:i], line[i:]

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def count_k(line, k):
    '''Count expressions that can be formed from line
    and sum to k mod M'''
    recursion_sum = sum(count_k(prefix, (k - int(suffix)) % M) 
                        + count_k(prefix, (k + int(suffix)) % M)
                        for prefix, suffix in all_splits(line))

    return ((int(line) % M) == k) + recursion_sum

def count_ugly(line):    
    '''Count expressions that can be formed from line
    and sum to an ugly number mod M'''
    return sum(count_k(line, k) for k in uglies)
```

Comment: Why not `all_splits = ((line[:i], line[i:]) for i in range(1, len(line)))`?

Comment: @RenéG That's good too.

Answer (score 5):

```
M = 2*3*5*7
uglies = list(filter(lambda n: (int(n)%2 == 0 or
                                int(n)%3 == 0 or
                                int(n)%5 == 0 or
                                int(n)%7 == 0),
                     range(M)))
```

Why the `int(...)` calls? Surely `range` returns integers?

---

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(line, k=None):
    if k == None:
        return sum([f(line, k) for k in uglies])
```

I'm not really a Python programmer so I'm not sure how Pythonic it is, but to me this overloading is a code smell. I would prefer to split out one function which takes just the line and another which does the real work.

Also, what is `k`? I managed to figure it out by reverse engineering, but a short comment would have helped a lot.

---

```
    return sum([
        (1 if (int(line) % M) == k else 0),

        sum([f(line[:p],
               (k-int(line[p:])) % M)
             for p in range(1, len(line))]),

        sum([f(line[:p],
               (k+int(line[p:])) % M)
             for p in range(1, len(line))]),
        ])
```

Again, it would be nice to have a short comment explaining why the recursion works on suffixes (and proving that it's correct, which isn't obvious, because it would seem to allow inserting a `-` before the first digit of the line in contradiction to the spec).

It would also be nice to see a justification for working on string slices rather than using integers with div/mod by powers of 10.

Comment: `int(n)` -- ya, that was copied from an earlier version that took chars. Oops.

Comment: Regarding correctness: ya, if this were production code, I'd prove it. It doesn't allow a `-` before the first digit because `p` starts at `1`. If `p` started at `0` then it would count operators before the first digit.

Comment: Regarding overloading: ya, that's one of the things I'd like feedback on, idk if it's good or bad.

Comment: Regarding using strings instead of ints: wouldn't I have to split it into a list of ints, and then combine them together every time I want to take modulus? Sounds like more work.

Comment: @RenéG, I'm pretty sure that it *does* allow a `-` before the first digit: what does `k-int(line[p:])` mean if it's not putting a `-` before the first digit? (I know why *I* think it works, but the fact that we disagree on what it's doing, let alone why it's correct, reinforces the need to comment clearly why it works).

Comment: Using ints instead of strings would use `divmod` with powers of 10. No need to decompose into an array of digits.

Comment: `p` starts at `1`. So suppose `p == 1`. Then `line[:p]` and `line[p:]` are both non-empty (since `len(line) > 1`). The minus/plus sign is inserted in between the two slices. So because both slices are non-empty, the minus/plus sign cannot be inserted at the very beginning or the very end.

Comment: Regarding divmod: ya, I guess that would work. Thanks. I'm not sure which approach is cleaner, though; I do like the slice notation, as I feel it is more readable. It's just annoying having to constantly convert to `int`.

Comment: Another way to see that it can't allow a `-` before the first digit: just consider `f('10')`. You'll get `1`, since it only counts `10`. If it counted `+/-` before the first digit, you would get `3`, because it would count `+10` and `-10`.

Comment: @RenéG, you're right: [`f('10')` does give `1`](http://ideone.com/yG6k6O). But that's a bug: it should give 2 because `10` is not ugly but `1+0` and `1-0` are.

Comment: No, ugly means divisible by a single digit prime. 1 is not a prime. 10 is divisible by 2 and 5, which are primes.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. But still: the three sums it's considering from input `10` are `10`, `0-1`, and `0+1`. Unless I've misunderstood `k`, which (since it isn't documented) is possible.

Comment: It's considering `10, 1-0, 1+0`. `k` is the equivalence class of the sum.